# How to mark common elements as checked in checkbox php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.
 The elements of the second array `$array2` will be displayed through check boxes.
 I want the common elements of both lists to be marked as checked and rest left unchecked.

```
$array1 = array("a", "b");

$array2 = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
```

Comment: merge elements into one array `($array3)`, loop over `$array3` and then use `in_array()` twice to check if the current element you are on is in both arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
$common = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

printf('<input type="checkbox" %s ...>', in_array('a', $common) ? 'checked' : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop on array2 and then search in array1, if it exists then mark the checkbox. Example:

```
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
  if (array_search($value,$array1) !== FALSE) {
    //$array2 element $value found in $array1
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$value' checked />";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array2 as $value) {
  echo (array_search($value,$array1) !== FALSE) ? "<input type='checkbox' name='$value' checked /> $value </br>" : "<input type='checkbox' name='$value'  /> $value </br>";
}
```